# Windows 7 no network (Guest) in Hyper-V Win 8.1 (Host)

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v

The following Setup

- Win 8.1 Pro (Host)
- Hyper-V
- VM with Windows 7 SP1 (guest)
- in Hyper-V -> Virtual Switch to External network and "Allow management ... " checked
- VM was assigned the virtual switch ... (btw. the network works in a different VM that uses Win Server as guest)

In the WIN 7 VM, I have no network connection and Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network Connections is blank ... nothing ...

It's a fresh install (did it 3 times)

Any suggestions, ideas? Is this a win 7 or a hyper v problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the VM have a virtual network adapter enabled?  Does it show up in the VM's Windows Device Manager?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved this by installing the hyper-v integration services. From guest connection window go to Action > insert intergration services setup disk > you will then be prompt with the setup disk on the vm and then you can install.